# Design for Hi-Res Screen in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8

This may be a completely dumb question... but I'm new to HTML/CSS, so don't hate. I'm using this in my CSS for Hi-Res background images.

```
 @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
 .pin_placeholder {

background-image: url(../images/taxi_pink@2x.png);
background-size: 150px 61px;

    }
```

It works fine, but what if someone tries to access this via IE 8 and below with a hi-res screen? Background size isn't supported in those IE versions, but I don't know how else to include background images. Am I completely wrong on this

Comment: Look up the term "Graceful Degradation" and I think that will give you a framework on using css features that may not be fully cross-browser supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is safe to assume that user running IE8 or below is still using Windows XP. Hi-Res display has to be properly supported in order to make use of the higher pixel density. Otherwise it is using pixels in 1:1 ratio, so what looks like 1440px x 900px on a Macbook Pro (with pixel density of 227 ppi) becomes 2880 x 1800px in Windows XP with half of the density (I see that when running Windows in a Virtual Machine).

Therefore I believe it is safe to assume that at the moment at least % of users with a configuration allowing them to run IE8 natively on a high resolution screen is so low that there is no need to cater for them (after all, all they get is improved image rendering, nothing else).

Comment: Perfect - Thanks Chris... That's what I thought, but I wanted to double check.